# Ignoring a reserved keyword if part of object access

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr, antlr4

In SQL, you cannot use a reserved keyword as a column name under normal circumstances, such as:

```
SELECT select FROM tbl
```

It must be quoted if it conflicts with a reserved keyword, such as:

```
SELECT `select` FROM tbl -- depending on the identifier quoting syntax
```

However, there is one case where this can be entirely ignored, and that is when the object is already qualified, such as:

```
SELECT tbl.select FROM tbl
SELECT function() . select
```

In my current grammar I have the following rules:

```
parser grammar DBParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}

root
    : selectStatement? (SEMI selectStatement)* SEMI EOF?
    ;

selectStatement
    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)* COMMA?
    ;

selectItem
    : expr (AS? IDENTIFIER)?
    ;

expr
    : IDENTIFIER
    ;
```

```
lexer grammar DBLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
COMMA               :           ',';                        // Argument list, Select list, etc.
SEMI                :           ';';                        // Statement terminator
SELECT              :           'SELECT';                   // SELECT *...

IDENTIFIER
    : [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*
    ;

WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

And a currently-valid input for this would be:

```
SELECT col1, xxx, xxx;
```

[image]

How could I modify the grammar such that I can allow a statement such as:

```
SELECT tbl.select, tbl . select;
```

A few notes on dialects:

- Postgres, BigQuery allow spaces between the `.`.
- MySQL does not allow spaces.
- SQLite, SQLServer do not allow this and even leafs on a path must be quoted.

---

In a way it's almost like I'm trying to do this:

```
expr
    : IDENTIFIER (DOT (expr **OR_ANYTHING**))?
    ;
```

Comment: `SELECT tbl.select FROM tbl` is invalid ANSI/ISO SQL. It doesn't matter that the lower case select is qualified, a reserved word as identifier must always be delimited.

Comment: Space(s) before/after the <period> are valid syntax.

Comment: @jarlh right, but be that as it may, many db engines support that: https://gyazo.com/9c77b1f50ba9adf01a3b79f84714fba5

Answer (score 0):

You can try extracting the identifier from the `expr` so you have more control of it, allowing the following types of allowable path-identifiers:

```
tbl.select
tbl.field
field
tbl
```

Here is the approach that I used:

```
parser grammar DBParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}

root
    : selectStatement? (SEMI selectStatement)* SEMI EOF?
    ;

selectStatement
    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)* COMMA?
    ;

selectItem
    : expr (AS? IDENTIFIER)?
    ;

identifierWithOptionalPath
    : IDENTIFIER (DOT (IDENTIFIER|reservedKeyword))*
    ;

expr
    : identifierWithOptionalPath
    ;

reservedKeyword
    : SELECT
    | AS
    ;
```

```
lexer grammar DBLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
COMMA               :           ',';                        // Argument list, Select list, etc.
DOT                :           '.';                        // Statement terminator

SEMI                :           ';';                        // Statement terminator
SELECT              :           'SELECT';                   // SELECT *...
AS                  :           'AS';                   // SELECT *...

IDENTIFIER
    : [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*
    ;

WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

And an example of the output -- notice all of the `selectItem`s are valid except for the naked `select`:

[image]